# Can't find fuse in Kia Sedona

Tags: kia, fuse

My 2006 Kia Sedona Carnival has suddenly stopped locking/unlocking with the remote. Battery in the fob is fine. At the same time the radio doesn't work. Fuse on radio is fine.  Can't find a particular fuse that might feed both. I changed the radio months ago, and both that and the remote worked, so they're probably not integrated. Where might it be located? Or any other bright ideas?

Comment: Radio doesn't work: It doesn't power up and show lights, numbers, words? Or it powers up but you get only static on AM, nothing on FM? Which is it?

Comment: @MTA - Absolutely dead - no display.

Answer (score 1):

The radio and the remote receiver module may share a power or ground wire in common. You may have disturbed something when you installed the new radio.

Suggest you remove the new radio and take a peek at all the wiring you can see. Look for anything disconnected, look for splices that have come loose, ground points from which the connector has pulled off, etc. Confirm that all connectors that are supposed to snap together actually do snap, and any splices, inline taps or crimp connectors are good.